# Autolisp user function overloading

Tags: autolisp

You can read this on AutoCAD knowledge website:
"Note: You can define multiple user functions with the same name, but have each definition accept a different number or type of arguments."
Has anybody using this feature? I tried but does not work at all.
I can call only the latest defined function.If I call like this `(file::AppendFile arg1)` then autocad said I give too less argument
[image]

Comment: does `::` have some special meaning as a part of a symbol name in Autolisp, or is it just a convention you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Note: You can define multiple user functions with the same name, but have each definition accept a different number or type of arguments."

This is not possible in AutoLISP: the last `defun` expression evaluated will overwrite all previous definitions of the symbol in the namespace - hence, in your example the `file:AppendFile` function would require two arguments, as the second `defun` expression will immediately redefine the function.

The only way to supply two arguments (other than supplying a list of arguments of varying length) would be to evaluate the `file:AppendFile` function prior to the evaluation of the second `defun` expression.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not at a computer with AutoCAD installed, so I can't check if AutoLISP works the way the documentation says it should, but I do know I've seen a workaround to pass a variable number of arguments into a function.

The trick is to pass all your arguments as a single list, and then process that list in the body of the function.  For example:

```
(defun myFunction (argsList / path header)
  (setq path (car argsList))
  (setq header (cadr argsList))
  (someFunction path "a" header)
)
```

... and then you'd call your function with `(myFunction '("arg1"))` or with `(myFunction '("arg1" "arg2"))`.

Note that in my examples above I'm using the list constructor literal, so it will pass in the actual strings `"arg1"` and `"arg2"`. If you want to pass in the contents of variables, you'd need to use the form `(myFunction (list var1 var2))` instead, because `(myfunction '(var1 var2))` would pass in the symbols `'var1` and `'var2` instead of their values.

It's a little bit ugly, but it's an option.